# how to add data per user in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-datastore

I have these rules in my cloud firebase database.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Collection named "users", document named after the userId
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

How to add data into database with these rules ?
I want to to use it on web.

Currently when i try to insert data using this code

```
db.collection("users").add({
    first: "Ada",
    last: "Lovelace",
    born: 1815
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

I got this error 
Error adding document: Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: @DougStevenson i have read that. But there is no example of that kind.
I have applied these rules so that a user can access only their own data.
But now i don't know how to insert data.
because it has to include user id with it but i don't know how to include it

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more clear about what you're trying to accomplish?  As is stands now, the question is very vague.  All you really have is some rules.

Comment: @DougStevenson please check now !

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("users").doc(userUid).set({
    first: "Ada",
    last: "Lovelace",
    born: 1815
})...
```

`add()` will create a unique *id/key* in this case you know which is the document, because it is the user document, so you have to use the user uid.